# Feed Content of a File to a Bash Script

Tags: bash, dig

I'm trying to construct a script that will run a command using the contents of two files, and append the results of that command to another file.

My two files:

1. `nameservers` - contains the addresses of my DNS.
2. `hostnames` - contains hostnames that needs to be resolved against the nameservers.

I need to pass the contents of `nameservers` and `hostnames` to this command:

```
dig @[content of nameservers file] -t a [content of hostnames]
```

Then each run it will extract the query time value and append it into a file in the following format:

```
[nameserver1] [query time value]
```

Like:

```
1.1.1.1 100
2.2.2.2 120
3.3.3.3 115
```

Comment: And your specific question would be? (I'm guessing it's how do I do this?)

Comment: Have you read BashFAQ #1 (at http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)?

Comment: I guess you need to pass all hostnames for each nameserver, isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a way:

```
#!/bin/bash
hostnames=`cat hostnamesfile`
cat nameserversfile | while read n; do
  echo "$hostnames" | while read h; do
    echo -n "$n "
    dig @$n -t a $h | grep 'Query time' | grep -o '[0-9]\+'
  done
done > resultsfile
```

Comment: This is rather horrible.  The [useless `cat`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html) should be easy to fix and `read -r` is also easy to change, but the rest of it should really be similarly refactored. Hint: useless use of `grep`; maybe read the hosts file into an array if you don't want to read it multiple times.

Comment: reasonable point, but based on the OP, i wanted to make the answer as understandable as possible.